# PHP if condition doesn't work

Tags: php, json, if-statement

My html form

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="sel1">Select Class:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="class_name">
    <?php $query=$con->query("SELECT * FROM class ORDER BY id ASC") or die($con->error);
        while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['class_name']?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     </select>
    <label>Add Section: </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="section_name" value="A">A</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="section_name" value="B">B</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="section_name" value="C">C</label>
</form>
```

Ajax

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var class_id = $("#class_name").val();
        var section_name = [];
        $("input[name='section_name']:checked").each(function(){
            section_name.push(this.value);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'insert_section.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {class_id:class_id,section_name:section_name},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

I am inserting array data in database through ajax. Insertion of data succeeded without implementing any condition. When I try to implement if condition, it doesn't work. What is error in following code

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$class_id = $_POST['class_id'];
$section_name = $_POST['section_name'];
$section_name = implode(",",$section_name);
$query=$con->query("SELECT * FROM section") or die($con->error);
while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(($class_id==$row['class_id'])&&($section_name==$row['section_name'])){
        echo json_encode('Section -'.$section_name.' has already assigned in '.$class_id);
    }
    else{
        $query2=$con->query("INSERT INTO section(class_id,section_name) VALUES('$class_id','$section_name')") or die($con->error);
    echo json_encode($section_name);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the output?

Comment: Log what is in `class_id` `$row['class_id']` `$section_name` `$row['section_name']` and check if that's the expected values

Comment: since we don't know what your data looks like, or what behaviour you intended, and you haven't mentioned any exceptions occurring, we can't really say what is wrong - for a start, we don't know what you deem to be "wrong" behaviour and what you expect as the "right" behaviour.

Comment: Also another note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like this.

Comment: $section_name is an array how can you check it with $row['section_name']

Comment: @ADyson, Please see updated question

Comment: You would be better to check the section names individually, rather than one big string. Also this shows your database design is wrong, you should not store multiple values inside one field in a relational database. It makes it harder to get the data items back again, and it will be hard to do other things like count how many of each item is recorded, that kind of thing. You should store one row per section name, all with the same class_id.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks for your valuable information, is it best to store each data in one row individually than whole data in same row ? I have stored all section in same (single) row using separator.

Comment: Yes that's the correct design, otherwise your data is not properly normalised and is not truly relational data. If you're going to use a relational database, you should use it correctly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You are imploding the $_POST section list

```
$section_name = implode(",",$section_name);
```

so this condition may not work :

```
$section_name==$row['section_name']
```

depending on your $_POST section ordering

Comment: that's a potential _explanation_, but it's not really a _solution_. If you're going to write an answer, you have to explain how to fix it as well